# Python pandas.read_excel store empy cells as 'None' instead of Nan values

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Currently I'm working with pandas and Excel. I've got excel sheet to process with lots of empy cells. Pandas recognize them as Nan values when parsing. I know how to get rid of them by passing this into pandas excel reading method.

```
pandas.read_excel(keep_default_na=False)
```

or

```
pandas.read_excel(na_filter=False)
```

But I would like to store empy cells as 'None' string instead. Is there any way to do that when reading  a Excel file?
Regards,
Ed.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? `pandas` has put a lot of thought into [handling missing data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html). Generally representing missing data with values `pandas` doesn't recognize as null (in this case `'None'`) only causes issues and complications later on.

Comment: Agree with @ALollz... it's best to leave them as NaNs so things don't break in weird/horrible ways and fill the values only for display/output purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Load the data and hold it into a data frame named let's say 'df'.
And the next step is to use df.fillna('value of your choice')

```
df = pandas.read_excel(keep_default_na=False)
df = df.fillna('None')
```

if you print df now, it will show as per your requirement.

Example :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 3], [3, 2, 4], [5]])
df = df.fillna('None')
print(df)

      0     1     2
   0  1     3  None
   1  3     2     4
   2  5  None  None
```

Hope this helps.
Please comment if you think this is not what you wanted.

Comment: I knew that but I was wondering if there's a way to do it at reading time. Thanks for support and your reply anyway!